# How to Prove these Product to Sum Trig Identities

Tags: trigonometry, angle

$$ \sin(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(a-b) + \sin(a+b)) $$

$$ \sin(a)\sin(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b)) $$

$$ \cos(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-b) + \cos(a+b)) $$

How do you derive these formulas from other Trig Identities such as any of:

- Angle Addition Identities
- Pythagorean Trig Identity
- Half Angle Identities
- Double Angle Identities

Or, if it can't be proven from other identities, what's the simplest way to prove them?  Would prefer not to have a geometric proof from scratch for these, and be able to remember them by just remembering other more basic ones.

Comment: They are all the direct result of [angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

Comment: How do I get from angle sum identities to those formulas?

Comment: For example, to obtain the first identity, halve the sum of the $\sin(a+b)$ and $\sin(a-b)$ identities.

Comment: @bgcode Just simplify the RHS, you will get the LHS.

Comment: For plugging into the angle sum identities, would I plug in $a + 0$, $b + 0$?  I tried that but just get back the starting point. What should I plug in for the addition if it just starts out as $a$ and $b$ as inputs?

Comment: $$\sin(a-b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) - \sin(b)\cos(a).$$ $$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a).$$ What happens when you add the two RHS's together?

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you.  I guess I didn't see this because I assumed I would start with either the final LHS or RHS to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to commenters for explaining this:

$$\begin{align}
\sin(a-b)&=\sin(a)\cos(b)−\sin(b)\cos(a) \\ \\
\sin(a+b)&=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a) \\ \\
\sin(a-b) + \sin(a+b) &= 2\sin(a)\cos(b) \\ \\
\sin(a)\cos(b) &= \frac{\sin(a-b) + \sin(a+b)}{2}
\end{align}$$